# Replace missing values using not empty values using identifier in panel data Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this table:

```
    Index     RUC       CIIU     Ejercicio
    1330    20100003512         2000
    1185    20100003512         2001
    2208    20100003512         2002
    3226    20100003512         2003
    4233    20100003512         2004
    5240    20100003512         2005
    6271    20100003512         2006
    7311    20100003512         2007
    8386    20100003512         2008
    9505    20100003512         2009
    10637   20100003512 2732.0  2010
    11799   20100003512 2732.0  2011
    12984   20100003512 2732.0  2012
    14160   20100003512 2732.0  2013
    15342   20100003512 2732.0  2014
    16543   20100003512 2732.0  2015
    17767   20100003512 2432.0  2016
    18990   20100003512 2432.0  2017
    20213   20100003512 2432.0  2018
    21424   20100003512 2432.0  2019
    13200   20100004322         2000
    1184    20100004322         2001
    2207    20100004322         2002
    3225    20100004322         2003
    4232    20100004322         2004
    5239    20100004322         2005
    6270    20100004322         2006
    7310    20100004322         2007
    8385    20100004322         2008
    9504    20100004322         2009
    10636   20100004322 2221.0  2010
    11798   20100004322 2221.0  2011
    12983   20100004322 2221.0  2012
    14159   20100004322 2221.0  2013
    15341   20100004322 2221.0  2014
    16542   20100004322 2221.0  2015
    17766   20100004322 2221.0  2016
    18989   20100004322 2220.0  2017
    20212   20100004322 2220.0  2018
    21423   20100004322 2220.0  2019
```

As you see I have three variables: RUC, CIIU and Ejercicio. RUC is my identifier and Ejercicio is my time variable. I would like to replace the empty values in the CIIU column using the available values, for example, in this case should be:

```
   Index     RUC             CIIU    Ejercicio
    1330    20100003512 2432.0  2000
    1185    20100003512 2432.0  2001
    2208    20100003512 2432.0  2002
    3226    20100003512 2432.0  2003
    4233    20100003512 2432.0  2004
    5240    20100003512 2432.0  2005
    6271    20100003512 2432.0  2006
    7311    20100003512 2432.0  2007
    8386    20100003512 2432.0  2008
    9505    20100003512 2432.0  2009
    10637   20100003512 2732.0  2010
    11799   20100003512 2732.0  2011
    12984   20100003512 2732.0  2012
    14160   20100003512 2732.0  2013
    15342   20100003512 2732.0  2014
    16543   20100003512 2732.0  2015
    17767   20100003512 2432.0  2016
    18990   20100003512 2432.0  2017
    20213   20100003512 2432.0  2018
    21424   20100003512 2432.0  2019
    13200   20100004322 2221.0  2000
    1184    20100004322 2221.0  2001
    2207    20100004322 2221.0  2002
    3225    20100004322 2221.0  2003
    4232    20100004322 2221.0  2004
    5239    20100004322 2221.0  2005
    6270    20100004322 2221.0  2006
    7310    20100004322 2221.0  2007
    8385    20100004322 2221.0  2008
    9504    20100004322 2221.0  2009
    10636   20100004322 2221.0  2010
    11798   20100004322 2221.0  2011
    12983   20100004322 2221.0  2012
    14159   20100004322 2221.0  2013
    15341   20100004322 2221.0  2014
    16542   20100004322 2221.0  2015
    17766   20100004322 2221.0  2016
    18989   20100004322 2220.0  2017
    20212   20100004322 2220.0  2018
    21423   20100004322 2220.0  2019
```

My current code is:

```
for i in range(len(data_trimestral)):
    data_trimestral['Ejercicio'][i] == int(data_trimestral['Ejercicio'][i])
lista_rucs = data_trimestral['RUC'][data_trimestral['Ejercicio'] > 2009].tolist()
lista_ciiu = data_trimestral['CIIU'][data_trimestral['Ejercicio'] > 2009].tolist()
tuple_data = tuple(zip(lista_rucs, lista_ciiu))
for i in range(len(data_trimestral)):
    for a,b in tuple_data:
        if data_trimestral['Ejercicio'][i] < 2010:
            data_trimestral['CIIU'][data_trimestral['RUC'][i] == a] = b
```

But it looks like does not working because take a lot of time to  make it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say " I would like to replace the empty values in the CIIU column using the available values " ? Why did you fill all the empty values with 2432?

Comment: Because CIIU is an international classifier of enterprises, but I 'cleaned the data because before of 2010, there was the CIIU version 3.0 and after of 2010, the use is CIIU version 4.0 and have a little bit differences between them. I would like to replace the most near value to the 2020 (In this case 2019)

Comment: I still pretty much didn't understand from where you want to fetch that particular data, but the solution to your current problem, which you say is that it's taking too long to run, you may want to use a multiprocessing cycle here.

You may use the multiprocessing.pool.Pool for this. Pool has a map function which allows you to run multiple iterations parallelly. 

If you can share the entire input, I can attempt at a better solution, if possible

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it could kinda confuse to explain. I just want replace the empty value from the column 'CIIU' with the values in the year 2019 (considering the column 'Ejercicio' as Years). For example, in the table I have two identifiers:  20100004322 and 20100003512, so I would like to take the value of 'CIIU' in the year 2019, first for 20100004322 2432.0  and put it in the blank values from the column CIIU (2000  to 2009).

Comment: For this you can simply take out the latest value from the dataframe using:

`newdf = df[(df['RUC'] == 20100004322) & (df['Ejercicio'] == 2019)]'

After this just use iloc and extract the value of CIIU from the newdf and replace it with the nan values. if you want further customisation you can use a for loop to loop through every row of the df and check if the year matches between 2000 to 2009 and if it does, just simply apply the value from iloc to the empty cell